# Firebase Cloud Messaging statistics for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way to see number of successfully sent and failed push notifications / messages in Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) ? I know I could just use Firebase Notifications but I would then have to use their console to send push notifications which is not practical for my use case.

Google explains how to get access to statistics on andoid [on this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268). But is there also a way for iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not ideal, you can use the Android Developer console to get statistics on your messages sent to iOS. Once you have the message IDs or the device IID tokens.

Answer (score 1):

- 1) Go on this page https://console.firebase.google.com/
- 2) Click on    notifications (on the left bar)
- 3) Click left on the notification    that you sent.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That is true for notifications sent out through Firebase Notifications but not for notifications sent out through FCM Rest API.